# Rewrite URLs in a Custom Post Type with Multiple Taxonomies

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm trying to filter the content of a custom post type, but I can only get it to read the first variable.

The custom post type has 3 associated taxonomies that if I pass them through GET in the URL it reads them to me without problem.

I must be doing something wrong, but I've tried everything without success.

This is the code I am using:

```
function url_buscador( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'inmuebles/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=inmuebles&tipo_de_operacion=$matches[1]',
        'inmuebles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=inmuebles&tipo_de_operacion=$matches[1]&tipo_de_inmueble=$matches[2]',
        'inmuebles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=inmuebles&tipo_de_operacion=$matches[1]&tipo_de_inmueble=$matches[2]&zona=$matches[3]'
        );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'url_buscador' );
```

I hope you can help me :)